# How do you make a fully square button?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Is there a simple way to make a fully square `Button`? Normally, a `Button` is a little rounded, so how do I achieve this?

Comment: Check it out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32257/A-Style-for-Round-Glassy-WPF-Buttons. It was like first result i have found in google. :P

Comment: In future, if you want to know how to change some specific visual component of a control in WPF, or just wonder how it's constructed, it is useful to take a look into its structure using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Stop bombing your question titles with tags, they *do not* belong there.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know. I'm new to this. Just thought that it'll be easier when someone else is looking for this question.

Comment: Haha, I didn't know SO had tag police.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean to have width = height then see [WPF dynamic layout: how to enforce square proportions (width equals height)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981705/wpf-dynamic-layout-how-to-enforce-square-proportions-width-equals-height)

If you mean to have square corners then set the **CornerRadius** of the Border to zero:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SquareButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">  
<Border CornerRadius="0"/>  
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then the button uses that template:

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource SquareButton}"/>
```

Comment: He wants to get rid of the rounding as far as I can see

Comment: That is correct, but still maintaining the button effect. Ivan Crojach Karačić I have used your solution but I also want to keep the button effect. Do I really have to use Blend to do that or can you do it all i XAML?

Comment: You just need to update the control template for your button which is why I'm only showing the relevant bit. This is just a case of editing XAML

Answer (score 5):

Just  create a custom button style...something like this

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="Arial Narrow" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="13" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF1733D2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="#FF1733D2">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you have Blend click on the button... edit style -> edit current... and get rid of the corner radius I think

Comment: You don't need to have Blend but it's a nice to have if you want to make something that needs to look a little bit better :)