# Windows Phone Xaml: Force square proportioned container (aspectratio 1:1)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need a container with square shape, but it has to be as big as it cans, but without be bigger of the parent.

I tried with the choosen answer from here:
[WPF dynamic layout: how to enforce square proportions (width equals height)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981705/wpf-dynamic-layout-how-to-enforce-square-proportions-width-equals-height)

but it creates a square bigger than the parent, what I need is a square that fits with the parent (like when you put in an image Stretch=Uniform).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="outer" Background="Cyan" Width="200" Height="400">
    <Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=outer}">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Fine, but, if the user rotates the phone it doesn't work well (work well in your example because there is a fixed size, but obviously I need it without a fixed size) :-/

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to make the square smaller than the parent by using `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`.

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Grid Background="Red"
        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=Grid}}"
        MaxHeight="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType=Grid}}">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The parent `Grid` fits the whole screen, and the child `Grid` keeps its aspect ratio even on rotation.

**EDIT :**

Or simply use `ViewBox`

```
<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Grid Background="Red" MinWidth="1" MinHeight="1">
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

You can use this for any aspect ratio by changing the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` of the inner `Grid`