# How to make a resizable WPF window that keeps its aspect ratio?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, resolution, aspect-ratio

Right, what I have is a window I'd like to resize, however I'd also like it to keep its aspect ratio. I've read some questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471867/resize-a-wpf-window-but-maintain-proportions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288954/how-do-i-keep-aspect-ratio-on-scalable-scrollable-content-in-wpf)), however, the solutions either don't work or are really jittery and fail very often. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: please upvote the questions or place a bounty.

Comment: 1. your question is the same as those you linked -> duplicate. 2. then please state what you mean by "not working" or "jittery". 3. please don't be rude, as you're the one needing assistance

Comment: @mathieu 1. It is, but look atthe next answer. 2.  Jittery: on resize, it keeps going back and forth between the old size and the new one, and then when I let go it may work or it may not, usually the former. Not working: The same as jittery, except that at the end it never works. 3. Sorry, I was angry that I looked up the questions, posted them to avoid this, and then it just happened anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I would use Viewbox with Uniform stretching as window's top content container.

Comment: That kind of works, it does keep the inner content uniform, but it has letterboxing if you stretch it in another direction, and also it makes it fill everything. I normally keep padding around the grid, so the content isn't touching the edge. The viewbox makes the content touch the edge, which I don't really like.

Comment: Without the code to look at, I guess noone really will be able to help you. My suggestion is, that you provide details in your question post.

Comment: It should be applicable to most WPF windows, and a Viewbox with uniform stretching won't do that.