# Why WPF XAML front end looks diffrent on other machines?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a WPF C# application and every element of front end is adjusted in margins, for example:

```
<TabItem x:Name="ClipboardItem" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Century Gothic"  Height="60" Header="     
 Multi Clipboard" Background="#2a2a29" Foreground="#e7e8ea" Margin="-4,-7,-57,8">
```

On my computer, everything looks good and just how i wanted. Weird thing is about other PCs. For example on other PC2 element let's call it A looks diffrent and run over but on other PC3 element A looks exactly like on my PC but other element B looks totally diffrent. To the point, on other PCs some elements are just like they should be, but some elements are not. It's window application with rigidly set height and length. Could you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Positioning items in WPF using margins is never a good idea. Try using a Grid control or other layout panel.

Comment: You are using a font family that is not on the standard windows font list [Windows 10 font list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list).  if `Century Gothic` is not on the other PC, windows will substitute with another font and this font's metrics will cause the layout to change as the width of words (in pixels) will change based on the font family.  This is why @Peregrine comment the best course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all. computers can come in many different resolutions and aspect ratios. so if you want to fit them all. use GridView or a ViewBox (there's more but these are good for starters). and it's not recommended to use margins for most elements unless it's small and in a corner then again don't use that.

use something suitable instead of HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

```
<GridView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" > 
   <TabItem x:Name="ClipboardItem" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Century Gothic"  
   Height="60" Header=" Multi Clipboard" Background="#2a2a29" 
   Foreground="#e7e8ea">
</GridView>
```

Learn about Grid Views before you try this code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/gridview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

if you want to maintain the aspect ratio Use View Box:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/290229/10518289](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/gridview-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

One other thing to keep in mind that all computers you test on must run the same version of .Net Framwork or the latest.